# Was installing gcc 4.8, ran out of diskspace now cant use gui, how to fix?

Tags: gcc

I have tried removing programs, including the unfinished gcc 4.8 install, but i get the error unmet dependancies. All the files I have left are really important so i cant delete them. Is there any other way I can fix this?

Comment: gcc is already installed by default, why were you installing it again?

Answer (score 0):

Start by running `sudo apt-get install -f`. This should cater for the unsolved dependencies.

Then you could recover space with `sudo apt-get autoremove` and `sudo apt-get autoclean`.